# How to access array of object inside of array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
[
    {
        name:"Technology",
        logoImage:require("../../assets/g837.png"),
        subCategory:[
            "IT",
            "Networks",
            "Appliances",
            "Industrial Machines",
            "Medical technology",
            "robotics",
            "AI",
            "Electronics",
            "Explosives",
            "Machinery", 
            "Cryptocurrency",
            "Electric Vehicles",
            "Biotechnology"

        ]
    },
    {
        name:"Business",
        logoImage:require("../../assets/business.png"),
        subCategory:[
            "Industries",
            "Economics",
            "Journalism",
            "Labor",
            "Law",
            "Real estate",
            "Entrepreneurship",
            "Investment",
            "Banking",
            "Leadership",
            "Advertising",
            "Business Strategy", 
            "Marketing",
            "E-commerce"
        ]
    },
    {
        name:"Entertainment",
        logoImage:require("../../assets/entertainment.png"),
        subCategory:[
            "Comedy",
            "Dance",
            "Dramas",
            "Films",
            "Gaming",
            "Toys",
            "Gambling",
            "Comics",
            "Social sites"

        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I mean i want to access subCategory. How do i do that???

Comment: can you please elaborate more about what you are exactly trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variable for storing the JSON is called `dataSet`, you'll be doing

```
for(data of dataSet){
    console.log(data.subCategory)
}
```

Within that for loop, you can also loop through all the subCategory of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myArray = [
    {
        "subCategory":[
            "IT",
            "Networks"
        ]
    },
    {
        "subCategory":[
            "IT",
            "Networks"
        ]
    }
]

myArray.forEach((eachObject) => {
  console.log(eachObject.subCategory)
})
```

Let's say you have stored that array in a variable **myArray**

then you can easily iterate the value of subCategory with the help of forLoop.

```
myArray.forEach((eachObject) => {
    console.log(eachObject.subCategory)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a simple JS question, to access some data from array/object....

**To access the element inside array:**

```
array[index] // first element start from 0.
```

The above "element" can consider as a string, number, object or even an Array inside the Array.

**To access the element inside object:**

```
let obj = {a:100,b:200,c:300}

object.key //obj.a means will get the value of 100
```

or

```
object["key"] //obj["b"] means will get the value of 200
```

or

```
let x = "c"

object[variable] // obj[x] is equal to obj["c"] means will get the value of 300.
```

**So, to access "subCategory" from an array that inside an Array of object, you just have to combine the above tactic:**

```
var nestedArray = [
    {
        name:"Technology",
        logoImage:require("../../assets/g837.png"),
        subCategory:[
            "IT",
            "Networks",
            "Appliances",
            "Industrial Machines",
            "Medical technology",
            "robotics",
            "AI",
            "Electronics",
            "Explosives",
            "Machinery", 
            "Cryptocurrency",
            "Electric Vehicles",
            "Biotechnology"

        ]
    },
    {
        name:"Business",
        logoImage:require("../../assets/business.png"),
        subCategory:[
            "Industries",
            "Economics",
            "Journalism",
            "Labor",
            "Law",
            "Real estate",
            "Entrepreneurship",
            "Investment",
            "Banking",
            "Leadership",
            "Advertising",
            "Business Strategy", 
            "Marketing",
            "E-commerce"
        ]
    },
    {
        name:"Entertainment",
        logoImage:require("../../assets/entertainment.png"),
        subCategory:[
            "Comedy",
            "Dance",
            "Dramas",
            "Films",
            "Gaming",
            "Toys",
            "Gambling",
            "Comics",
            "Social sites"
        ]
    }
]


var subCategoryArray = nestedArray[0]["subCategory"] // return  ["IT", "Networks",...]
```

**If your array has multiple objects in there, then you will need to use for loop:**

```
var subCategoryArray = []
for(var i = 0; i < nestedArray.length; i++){
   subCategoryArray= subCategoryArray.concat(nestedArray[i]["subCategory"])
}

console.log(subCategoryArray) //return ["IT", "Networks",...,"Comics","Social sites"]
```